# Why is there no very famous open source CMS or e-commerce application written in Ruby?

Tags: php, ruby, open-source, content-management-system

The very famous open source CMS and e-commerce applications, i.e. Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, Prestashop, are all written in PHP.
But Ruby seems to be awesome (I don't know it that much).
Why is there no such project written in Ruby?
Or would there be one I do not know?

Answer (score 2):

I would say that at least one good reason is that Ruby is not used that much.

As a consequence :

- Not many people use Ruby

  - So not many entreprises will use Ruby for their commercial projects
  - So not many people will learn Ruby *(either at work or at school)*
- So not many applications are developped in Ruby
- So not many web-servers *(I'm especially thinking about shared hosting)* have Ruby installed
- So not many developper will use Ruby -- they want their open-source applications to run everywhere,
- and so on ;-)

Comment: But how about scala, Django, Rails and some more family members together? Together they are very often used, yet still have hardly any wellknown/often used CMSes as offspring.

Answer (score 1):

Just heard of : http://www.locomotivecms.com/

I've not tested it yet but it looks interesting.

I'm actually a php developer, working lot with Joomla, but I'll soon begin learning Ruby (some features just look awesome!, Like redefining operators,...) and Ruby On Rails for personal interest.

Answer (score 1):

**CMS**-es allow building sites, **Frameworks** allow building applications.

You don't build a game in Drupal. You won't even think about a large community in Joomla! No-one will even consider building a large communication-platform (chat) with Wordpress.

PHP comes from a differnet ERA. The web-era where we all build off-the-shelve sites. Where user-interaction just started becoming interesting. And where it was hard to get an affordable LAMP stack set up for your latest-greatest idea. I am talking before Y2000.

Now-a-days one can hardly build a website without Twitter connections, Facebook logins and complex backend communication with several services.

Back in the days, these kind of projects were almost always Java. They still are, to a degree. Governments, corporate portals, media: they all have complex, integrated web-environments. PHP will hardly be used for this.

While in theory something like that is possible with a CMS like Drupal, it is certainly not a cost-efficient project. A CMS was simply never meant for that.

A framework like Ruby on Rails allows you to build what your client wants, exactly: nothing more, nothing less. Which means that the end-result is not generic, but extremely opinionated. and as such, not releasable as a tool for the masses.

Comment: Last paragraph should read "A framework like Rails", right? Because Ruby is not a framework..

Comment: @poke: correct. Fixed it in an edit.

Comment: *"A framework like Ruby allows.."* Ruby is not a framework, "Ruby on Rails" is.

Comment: Thanks, Ivan. Already edited as per @pokes suggestion.

Comment: *"CMS-es allow building sites, Frameworks allow building applications."* CMS-es are not there to build website but to manage content of the websites. It's sort of obvious from the name.
Many of the CMSes are using frameworks underneth. Comparing CMS and framework is like comparing chassis and a car. 
The question was why there are no famous open source CMSes written on Ruby.

Comment: «Comparing CMS and framework is like comparing chassis and a car.» Which is why all cars look alike and are hardly customisable. For the customised needs (disabled ppl, racing, commerce, complex environments) one will start off with the chassis. Which is the **answer to your question**: many ppl need a car, fewer need a chassis to start with. But no-one will build an average ford-sedan starting with a chassis.

Comment: Also « Many of the CMSes are using frameworks underneth.» is not trough for the CMSes the QA picks out: Wordpress, Joomla, Drupal, are all built from scratch, and have no framework underneath. I am not sure about Prestashop, never developed with or for it.

Comment: *"But no-one will build an average ford-sedan starting with a chassis"* That exactly how most of the cars are build - starting with a chassis... But it's not the point. 
You are answering a wrong question. The question was why there is no popular open source CMSes written in ROR? And you are going into a discussion about frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is cheaper and easier to host on a shared-server - installing `mod_php` into Apache is easy, and it uses less RAM than Ruby. So more providers provide PHP-hosting, and more less-technical people use PHP software.

Ruby *does* have some good CMSes - e.g. [Radiant](http://radiantcms.org/) or [Refinery](http://refinerycms.com/) - and ecommerce solutions  e.g. [Spree](http://spreecommerce.com/).

Answer (score 0):

CMSs are, at least originally were, end-user products. End user doesn't really care how awesome the language that the software was built on is. On the other hand, PHP has much bigger penetration with hosting sites and deployment of PHP applications mostly comes down to "unzip this to your host, go through the wizard and you're good to go". Ruby got standard way of deployment just recently. Knowing all that, developers were (and arguably still are) choosing PHP over other languages when starting to build mass-marketed products as CMSs are.